# script shell : copy part of line in a file and put it at the beginning

Tags: linux, shell, sed

I have a file looking like that

```
blabla1/blabla2/blabla3.ex
blabla4/blabla5/blabla6.ex
blabla7/blabla8/blabla9.ex
```

and with a script shell linux, I would like to change it to

```
blabla3 : blabla1/blabla2/blabla3.ex
blabla6 : blabla4/blabla5/blabla6.ex
blabla9 : blabla7/blabla8/blabla9.ex
```

I didnt succeed that with a sed command. My problem is copying text existing in a line at the beginning of each line.

Does anybody have a solution? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`awk` loves these things:

```
$ awk -F[/.] '{print $(NF-1),$0}' OFS=" : " file
blabla3 : blabla1/blabla2/blabla3.ex
blabla6 : blabla4/blabla5/blabla6.ex
blabla9 : blabla7/blabla8/blabla9.ex
```

#### Explanation

- `-F[/.]` set field separators to `/` or `.`.
- `print $(NF-1),$0` print the penultimate field and then the full line.
- `OFS=" : "` set output field separator to space + `:` + space.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanations it's very useful! I should try to learn awk commands it seems to be powerful

Comment: can OFS be putted before '{print...? nice solution @fedorqui . My beginners was awk -F"[/.]" '{print $3, " : ", $1"/"$2"/"$3".ex"}'

Comment: @josifoski note the approach you suggest would fail for a line like `blabla7/blabla8/blabla9/blabla10.ex` or `blabla9/blabla10.ex`. It is important not to be dependent of the number of fields, hence the usage of `NF-1` and `$0`. Regarding `OFS` before, yes: `-v OFS=" : "` would make.

Comment: I've tried to put OFS before '{print...' and it gives syntax eror. awk -F[/.] OFS=" : " '{print $(NF-1),$0}' @fedorqui

Comment: just mingling with awk, already upvoted, no need for answering this, tnx

Comment: @josifoski note you need `-v`: `awk -F[/.] -v OFS=" : " '{print $(NF-1),$0}' file`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this `sed`,

```
sed 's#^.*/\([^/]*\).ex#\1 : &#' yourfile
```

Comment: Good one! Note there is no need to `g`.

Answer (score 0):

for fun:

```
paste file file|sed 's@^\S*/@@;s/\.[^.]*\s/ : /'
```